# Sqlite3 error in adb command line

Tags: android, sqlite, adb

I try to fetch call log details from android emulator with below adb command line.

```
adb shell
#cd /data/data/com.providers.android.contacts/databases
# sqlite3 contacts.db
SQLite version 3.5.0
Enter ".help" for instructions
sqlite> .dump
.dump
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
COMMIT;
```

I have an error that i don't know what happen.

This is error in sqlite3

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: What is the error saying?

Comment: Could it mean that the data base is just empty? Are you sure that ``contacts.db`` is the right data base? "Contacts" doesn't sound like call log.

Answer (score 2):

When you try to open a non-exisiting database file, SQLite will happily create an empty one.

Check that the file actually exists (e.g., with `ls`).

(On your phone, the call log might be in another file such as `/data/data/com.sec.android.provider.logsprovider/databases/logs.db` or `/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db`.)